# Euler Phi Function and Divisibility

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, totient-function

**Question: Suppose that the positive integer n is divisible by 7.
Prove that $ 7φ(n) ≤ 6n $
When exactly does equality hold and why?**

I have concluded that if n is divisible by 7, it obviously cannot be prime. This eliminates the use of the equation $ φ(p^k) = p^k − p^{k−1} $.

I have had a lot of practice with $n$ being prime, but have not learned a whole lot when $n$ is not prime.

Comment: HINT: Write $n=7^k \cdot m$, where $m$ is not divisible by $7$. Then compute $\varphi(n)$, and see what happens.

Comment: I've gotten $ (7^{k} - 7^{k-1})\phi (m) $. I'm not quite sure how that helps me relate to $6n$

Comment: I have further simplified to get $$ (7^{k}-7^{k-1}) \phi (m) \le 6*7^{k-1}m $$

which seems obvious to me as to why the RHS would be greater than the LHS, but I need to explain it better than that

Comment: Try writing $7^k-7^{k-1}$ as $6\cdot7^{k-1}$

Comment: I actually just figured that part out! Silly me! Thanks though!

Answer (score 2):

Because $7$ divides $n$, $$\varphi(n)=n\prod_{p|n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)\le n\left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)$$ and$$7\varphi(n)\le7n\left(1-\frac{1}{7}\right)=6n$$

Answer (score 1):

By hypothesis, $n = 7^k m$ for some $k$, $m \in \mathbb{N}$, where $7 \nmid m$. Then $\gcd(7^k,m) = 1$, so $\varphi(7^k m) = \varphi(7^k) \varphi(m)$, so $$\begin{aligned}[t] 7 \varphi(n) = 7 \varphi(7^k m) = 7 \varphi(7^k) \varphi(m) &= 7 (7^k-7^{k-1}) \varphi(m) \\ &= 7\cdot 7^{k-1}(7-1) \varphi(m) = (7-1) 7^k \varphi(m) \leq 6 \cdot 7^k m = 6n.\end{aligned}$$

Comment: I'll leave it to you to check when equality holds.